# How to use wildcards and variable substitution in activemq camel routes

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I would like to set up a generic camel route that routes all messages to a set of queues to a queue with the same name and a suffix.  I'm thinking it would look something like this:

```
<camelContext id="camel" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="genericRoute">
        <from uri="activemq:queue:somequeues.*" />
        <to uri="${getMyQueueName}.moo" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

activemq talks about wildcards here: http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html but nothing more that I can find.

This may not even be possible but would be very handy if it is!

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried it? I think it should work as you described.

Answer (score 1):

See this FAQ about the `<to>` which is wrong in your example:

- http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: yes! that's exactly what I was looking for!  My googling skills need some work it seems. Thanks!